# Is there a multi-tenant data source in Spring Data Neo4J

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Looks like Spring Data JPA has support for selecting different databases per tenant in a multi-tenant application:

http://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/

Is there something similar in Spring Data Neo4J?

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible; Neo4J does not support multi-tenancy.**

However, there may be some options for getting around this. If you are absolutely determined to have multi-tenancy, you might consider setting up some sort of proxy/routing solution. Or you could host multiple servers on the same machine but on different ports.

But, any solutions would be workarounds. Spring Data Neo4J does not support multi-tenancy, and any of the proposed solutions will need additional tooling to map a tenant to a connection string, which is out-of-band of Spring Data.

Comment: To people in the future: [There is work actively being done on the Cypher spec to allow for multi-tenancy](https://github.com/boggle/openCypher/blob/CIP2017-06-18-multiple-graphs/cip/1.accepted/CIP2017-06-18-multiple-graphs.adoc). I suspect this might be a feature of Neo4j 4.0. If the link breaks, go to the openCypher repo on github.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you could handle it by a reasonable pattern: tenant by label.

In Neo4j 4.0 multi-tenancy and multi-database are promised.

If you do the label-based separation today, it's an easy move to multi-tenant in the DB infrastructure in the future.

It is expected to release by second half of 2019.

[Community neo4j](https://community.neo4j.com/t/proper-way-to-implement-multi-tenancy-on-neo4j/625/7)